# "float: left" not working as intended

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
.item {
  width: 33.33vw;
  height: 33.33vw;
  float: left;
}
#featured {
  background-color: green;
  width: 66.66vw;
}
#vertical {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 66.66vw;
}
#normal01 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#normal02 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="featured">
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="vertical">
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="normal01">
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="normal02">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm currently learning HTML/CSS and I can't seem to find anything on the web for such a basic "template". As you can see my pink and yellow squares doesn't want to collide with the top green rectangle. It's been around 2 hours that I'm trying different techniques without resolving this issue, could anyone point me to the right direction ?

What is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do, is float-left even the right way ?

Comment: Consider using one of the many CSS grid systems already out there, like Bootstrap or Foundation.

Comment: @ceejayoz Adding at least 200ko of CSS to produce a simple layout can't be considered as a good solution, IMHO.

Comment: @enguerranws All of the major CSS frameworks are modular these days. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ lets you pull out just the grid system easily, which winds up about 4 KB minified and gzipped.

Comment: As long as you use vh and vw which are new units, I assume you don't need old browsers support, that's why you should consider using Flexbox that will solve layout like this easily. I guess in a near future, we won't use float, clear, etc. anymore for layout purpose, so...

Comment: @ceejayoz That is still heavy just to achieve something that flexbox and other layout technics are designed to.

Comment: @enguerranws http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox says IE8 (still in widespread usage) doesn't support it, and IE11 has "partial support due to large amount of bugs present". Given that OP's having trouble floating divs, I'm not sure advising them to write their own grid system and jump to flexbox is at all responsible.

Comment: Floated elements became popular after the table era, since it was kind of a solution to the need of responsive design. Since a lot of different devices with different viewports were being used for navigating the web developing websites with tables was not viable anymore. This is why frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation got really popular. Today there are new options that will completely change web design which are Flexbox and Grid, you should read about those if you're interested in what's next, those two will probably replace float design just like float did with table.

Comment: @ceejayoz The asker said it's for learning purpose, that's why I talk about Flexbox. But it's just an example, if there's any compatibility issue (that asker asker didn't mention) any CSS native layout method will be a better solution than using a framework. Anyway, the asker uses vh and vw units. Fell free to check on caniuse :)

Answer (score 3):

To solve this particular situation, add `float: right` to `#vertical`. If it has `float: left`, no subsequent elements are allowed left of it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>
         body {
         margin: 0;
         }
         .container {
         width: 100vw;
         height: 100vh;
         background-color: red;
         }
         .item {
         width: 33.33vw;
         height: 33.33vw;
         float: left;
         }
         #featured {
         background-color: green;
         width: 66.66vw;
         }
         #vertical {
           float: right;
         background-color: blue;
         height: 66.66vw;
         }
         #normal01 {
         background-color: pink;
         }
         #normal02 {
         background-color: yellow;
         }
      </style>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="item" id="featured">
         </div>
         <div class="item" id="vertical">
         </div>
         <div class="item" id="normal01">
         </div>
         <div class="item" id="normal02">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```